# Is it a bug of Ruby parser?

Tags: ruby, bash

I have slimmed down an issue I am facing to an MWE. Can anybody confirm if it is a bug or I am missing something rudimentary?

**Platform**:

- Ruby 1.9.3p484 (2013-11-22 revision 43786) [x86_64-linux]
- GNU bash, version 4.3.11(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
- Ubuntu 14.04.2 x86_64

**Step 1**: Create a Ruby script as follows named `demo.rb`

```
puts "[Line 1]"
puts "* [Line 2] *"
```

**Step 2**: Create a driver script as follows named `driver`

```
#!/bin/bash

ret=`ruby ./demo.rb `
echo $ret
```

**Step 3**: Move both the files above inside an empty folder.

**Step 4**: Run `driver` from `bash`. As you can see, it's listing the contents of the parent directory with each `puts` call.

```
$ ./driver
[Line 1] demo.rb driver [Line 2] demo.rb driver
```

**Step 5**: If `demo.rb` is executed directly from `bash`, it produces:

```
$ ruby demo.rb 
[Line 1]
* [Line 2] *
```

Now, delete the asterisks(`*`) from both the ends of the `puts` string in the second line of `demo.rb`:

```
puts "[Line 1]"
puts " [Line 2] "
```

If I repeat step 4,

```
$ ./driver 
[Line 1] [Line 2]
```

If I repeat step 5,

```
$ ruby demo.rb 
[Line 1]
 [Line 2]
```

I can't understand the following:

1. Why does the output contain directory listing in the first attempt?
2. Why does removal of asterisks suppress the directory listing in the second attempt?
3. Why does the outputs differ in the second attempt if I repeat step 4 and step 5 respectively?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1 & 2: Nothing to do with Ruby, everything to do with Bash. `*` is a [glob](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glob_(programming)), which expands to the list of the filenames when present in a bash command. Try this:

```
$ echo *
$ a="*"; echo $a
$ a="DIR: * ; DIR AGAIN: *"; echo $a
```

3: Because `echo` prints its arguments separated by a space; and newlines are treated as spaces. Look at this:

```
$ a=`cat /etc/services`
$ echo $a
$ echo "$a"
```

The `echo $a` will smush all the lines into one. If you use the double quotes, you can protect the contents of `$a` to be treated as one argument, and the newlines are preserved. (Same logic would apply for `echo "$ret"`)

Answer (score 2):

Looks like standard glob expansion behaviour to me.

When you do `echo $ret` in your shell script, the `*` inside the string is expanded to the contents of the directory.

If you had put quotes around it `echo "$ret"`, then you would only see the literal `*` in the output. You would also see that the whitespace inside the variable was preserved (answering the third point in your question).

This is one of the reasons why you should always quote your variables!